# PriorityQueue Constructor in Java

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue

Given the example code:

```
Comparator<Node> comparator = this.createCompartor(algorithmChoice , matrix);

this.m_openList1 = new PriorityQueue<Node>(100, comparator);
```

What does the `100` in the `PriorityQueue` constructor stand for?

Comment: Did you try to read the documentation? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Comment: @Itay In future I would provide the Java 7 Javadoc as Java 6 is almost end of life. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the initial capacity of the `PriorityQueue`. You would generally specify the initial capacity explicitly if you knew before hand how many items you were going to add (or had an approximation).

This can also be seen in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue%28int,%20java.util.Comparator%29):

> `public PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity, Comparator<? super E> comparator)`
>
> Creates a PriorityQueue with the specified initial capacity that orders its elements according to the specified comparator.
>
> **Parameters:**
>   - `initialCapacity` - the initial capacity for this priority queue.
>   - `comparator` - the comparator used to order this priority queue. If null then the order depends on the elements' natural ordering.
>
> **Throws:**
>   - `IllegalArgumentException` - if `initialCapacity` is less than 1

In fact, most collections in Java have constructors that take an int argument specifying the initial capacity.

Comment: I am not getting what exactly the initial capacity mean here. Could you please explain it in bit more detail?  Does it mean there can't be more items than that value?